# ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-material-fileupload/matFileUpload.esm.js

Tags: angular5

I am working with angular5.I need to do file upload.
I refered this link [https://github.com/nishantmc/angular-material-fileupload][1]

I am getting error as
 ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-material-fileupload/matFileUpload.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/merge' in '\node_modules\angular-material-fileupload'
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-material-fileupload/matFileUpload.esm.jsModule not found: 
Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operators/startWith' in '\node_modules\angular-material-fileupload'

Help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could install the rxjs-compat package from npm.

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

It's designed for situations like this, where some code didn't migrate to rxjs 6 yet.